# enable SNMP monitoring for Java app with existing MBeans

Tags: jmx, snmp, java-7, snmp4j

I'm looking for an example to expose the methods already exposed via MBean server with SNMP.

I read that since Java6 this is already supported in the JDK, but I also found snmp4j as a library. But I couldn't find any example that fits my scenario, or would be helpful.

I already have MBeans registered to the MBeanServer, and I'm looking for a way to enhance the classes I already have in order to make them suitable for SNMP. I can't use mibgen, as it would be the other way around.

Maybe someone can give me an example on what I need to do in order to be able to monitor my application via some SNMP manager.

An example MBean would be

```
public interface ExporterMXBean {
public static String BEANNAME = "exporter:type=Exporter,name=Exporter";
String getOutputDirectory();
void setOutputDirectory(String outputDirectory);
void startExport();
    int getNumberOfThreadsWorking();
}
```

What would I need to add to the implementation of the interface, how would I register this to a MIB, and how would it be exposed/viewable to a Manager?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using SNMP4J-AgentJMX on top of SNMP4J-Agent and SNMP4J like the in the example of SNMP4J-AgentJMX called JvmManagementMibInst.java.

With this approach you do not modify your existing classes (MBeans). Instead your programm or generate a mapping which makes use of the above APIs.

A basic How-To on the necessary steps to create a SNMP agent based on some MBeans of a MBean server is described in the [SNMP4J-AgentJMX HowTo](https://oosnmp.net/confluence/x/DwBJ)

Comment: thank you, I managed to create a small application w/ scalars only that I can call via my created test manager, as well as with nagios